# Operator precedence in c with pointers

Tags: c, operator-precedence

How to analyse the precedence in following situation .

```
for (i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    *array_p++ = i*i;
    printf("%d\n",*arr++);
}
```

how is following code different from above.

```
for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    *arr = i*i;
    printf("%d\n",*arr);
    arr++; 
    printf("%d\n",(int )arr);
}
```

I am expecting same output but outputs are different for *arr value

Comment: I would suggest referring to a table like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence.

Comment: Did you mean to increment arr twice in the first example but not in the second?

Comment: Also, why would you expect the same output?  The first loop has one printf, the second loop has two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increment a pointer address and pointer's value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208021/how-to-increment-a-pointer-address-and-pointers-value)

Comment: Removed the gcc tag because this has nothing to do with gcc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postfix operators have higher precedence than unary operators, so `*x++` is parsed as `*(x++)`; the result of the expression `x++` (which is `x`) is dereferenced.

In the case of `*++x`, both `*` and `++` are unary operators and thus have the same precedence, so the operators are applied left-to-right, or `*(++x)`; the result of the expression `++x` (which is `x + sizeof *x`) is dereferenced.

Comment: In case of *++x, the operators dereference and suffix are applied right-to-left, not left-to-right. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 4):

Citing [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence), *postfix* ++ binds before unary *. This means that you have `*(arr++)`. For example, in the expression `*arr++ = 5`, `*arr` is assigned to 5, then `arr` is incremented.

In the K&R, this trick is used to write a concise version of memcpy. It's something like:

```
while (--size)
    *dest++ = *src++;
```

I'll post the correct example after I get home tonight.

**Edit:** Apparently, only postfix ++ has higher precedence. Wikipedia says prefix ++ has equal precedence.

Comment: did you mean `strcpy`: `while (*dst++ = *src++);`?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. I don't have the book with me so I'm going from memory.

Comment: @Oscar:if it is *++arr then it leads to segfault . why?

Comment: @Imposter: Work through the last iteration of the look by hand. Be very careful with when things happen and how the array cells are numbered.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to remember which has precedence when you consider prefix increment.

what has precedence here?

*++array = x; // pretty obvious

the same precedence rules go for the postfix expression so its rather easy.

The same goes for the cast operator.

(somestruct *)x + 1;

first the cast is done since if it wasn't the following wouldnt make sense

x + (int)1;

Comment: Thanks for you answer: almost 2 year old post :-)

Answer (score 2):

In the first sample code snippet,

```
    for (i=0; i<20; i++)
        {
          *array_p++ = i*i;
           printf("%d\n",*arr++);
    }
```

array_ptr is incremented first i.e address, and then the value computed from i*i is assigned to *array_ptr since evaluation takes in the order of right to left i.e *(array_ptr ++).

In the second sample of code snippet,

```
for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
{
  *arr = i*i;
printf("%d\n",*arr);
 arr++; 
printf("%d\n",(int )arr);
}
```

value computed from i*i is first computed and assigned to *arr, then pointer pointing to arr is incremented.

Hence there is difference in values among the 2 code snippets.

Comment: Thanks for you answer: almost 2 year old post

Answer (score 1):

Operators ++ and * have the same precedence (`postfix or prefix`).However the associativity in such cases is from right to left.
so in cases like

```
*ptr++ ==>  *(ptr++) 
*++ptr ==> *(++ptr)
++*ptr ==> ++(*ptr)
```

this link should give you more information on operators precedence and their associativity..
http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/c/c-precedence.html