# Function not updating an int field

Tags: c

Everything seems to working fine except for my SPOILED votes int is staying at 0 and not being updates by the function. I have tried adding a pointer thinking it would point to the object outside of the function which it does but the ++ function is not updating

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct candidates
{
 char name[20];
 int votes;
};
struct candidates electionCandidates[7];

void Initialize(struct candidates EC[]);
void Processvotes(struct candidates EC[], int *BadVote);
void printResults(struct candidates EC[], int *BadVote);

int main()

{

    int i, SPOIL = 0;

    Initialize(electionCandidates);
    Processvotes(electionCandidates, &SPOIL);
    printResults(electionCandidates, &SPOIL);

    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        printf("%s",electionCandidates[i].name);
        printf("%d\n\n",electionCandidates[i].votes);
    }

    printf("%d", SPOIL);

}

void Initialize(struct candidates EC[])
{
    int i;

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("elections.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)

    {
        fgets(EC[i].name, 20, (FILE*)fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}


void Processvotes(struct candidates EC[], int *BadVote)
{
        int TVOTE, i;

        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("elections.txt", "r");

        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            fgets(EC[i].name, 20, (FILE*)fp);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 365; i++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &TVOTE);

            if (TVOTE == 1)
                EC[0].votes++;
            if (TVOTE == 2)
                EC[1].votes++;
            if (TVOTE == 3)
                EC[2].votes++;
            if (TVOTE == 4)
                EC[3].votes++;
            if (TVOTE == 5)
                EC[4].votes++;
            if (TVOTE == 6)
                EC[5].votes++;
            if (TVOTE == 7)
                EC[6].votes++;

            if (TVOTE < 1 || TVOTE > 7)
                *BadVote++;
        }

        fclose(fp);
}

void printResults(struct candidates EC[], int *BadVote)
{

    int i, Win = 0, WinSCORE = 0, Runner = 0, RunnerSCORE = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {

        if (EC[i].votes > WinSCORE)
        {
            WinSCORE = EC[i].votes;
            Win = i;
        }

        if (EC[i].votes == WinSCORE)
        {
            RunnerSCORE = EC[i].votes;
            Runner = i;
        }
    }


    if (WinSCORE == RunnerSCORE)
    {
        printf("There was a tie between %s and %s who both got a total of %d votes each. There were %d spoiled votes\n", EC[Win].name, EC[Runner].name, WinSCORE, *BadVote);
    }

    else
        printf("%s won the election with a total of %d votes. There was a total of %d spoiled votes.\n", EC[Win].name, WinSCORE, *BadVote);


}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ignore the loop in main with printf statements for name votes and spoil was checking to see what the values were.

Comment: Use a switch case instead of such a long series of if and for <1 || > 7 you can use the default case. Along with as suggested (*BadVotes)++;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The postfix `++` operator takes precedence over the `*`; when you write `*BadVote++`, you're actually incrementing the pointer, not the value being pointed to. You should instead write `(*BadVote)++`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208021/how-to-increment-a-pointer-address-and-pointers-value) for more.

Comment: Oh OK. Always something so simple. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the precedence of the operators. Try this:
    if (TVOTE < 1 || TVOTE > 7)
       (*BadVote)++;