# int q = {1,2}; peculiar initialization list

Tags: c

I came across the below initialization , it is seen that VS2012
 shows an error complaining about too many initializers. in GCC it seems to
 return the first element as the value.

why is this peculiar initialization supported  in GCC?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int q = {1,2};
    char c = {'s','t','\0'};  /* c is 's' */
    printf("%d\n",q); /* prints 1*/
}
```

Comment: I wonder what it's doing with the remaining initializers:(

Comment: @Martin please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394871/const-char-a-string1-string2-and-pointer-arithametic . I got really bashed for this question, but it gets interesting when strings are involved :)

Comment: Have you seen this in code?  It seems like a bad idea, even if the compiler allows it.

Comment: If you enable warnings `gcc` will be really pissed off with this.

Comment: GCC 4.8.3 here outputs a warning *by default* (that is, without `-Wall` or anything).

Comment: Lots of warnings... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6691f8768208b710

Comment: @Deduplicator that's what I mean, why would this be useful anyway?

Comment: [A quick primer on initialization in C.](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/initialization.html)  This, combined with @haccks answer, should illuminate why it's only a warning.

Comment: My first thought was that it's a comma operator, discarding the `1` and yielding `2`. `1,2` is a valid expression. But the grammar requires an *assignment-expression* in that context, so a top-level comma operator is not permitted.

Comment: @KeithThompson allowing comma operator in this content would be horrible!

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Agreed, it would create ambiguities. (Though of course comma operators are allowed as long as they're not at the top level.)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### C11: 6.7.9 Initialization (p11):

> The initializer for a scalar *shall* be a single expression, **optionally enclosed in braces**.

Therefore, this is allowed

```
int q = {1};
```

You can enclose the initializer for scalar objects in braces (`{}`). Note the verb *shall* is used here. The standard says:

#### 5.1.1.3 Diagnostics (P1):

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined

So, it is up to the compiler how it handles

```
int q = {1,2};
```

Compiled on GCC 4.8.1 with flags `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra` and it raised a warning

```
[Warning] excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
```

Now the question is: [*What happend with the remaining initializers?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412577/int-q-1-2-peculiar-initialization-list/28412748#comment45158611_28412577)
It's a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=684635).

---

**Note:** C11: 6.5.17 (p3) says that the *comma operator* cannot appear in contexts where a comma is used to separate items in a list (such as arguments to functions or lists of initializers).

Do not confused the `,` in `{1,2}` with *comma operator*. As [Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412577/int-q-1-2-peculiar-initialization-list/28412748?noredirect=1#comment45166370_28412748) pointed out that, the *expression* in initializer to be an *assignment-expression* and it must not contain *comma operator* at top-level. That means it can be used within a parenthesized expression or within the second expression of a conditional operator in such contexts. In the function call

```
f(a, (t=3, t+2), c)
```

the function has three arguments, the second of which has the value `5`.

Comment: so the remaining initializers are ignored?

Comment: do you remember the following question , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394871/const-char-a-string1-string2-and-pointer-arithametic , The result is basically due to this?

Comment: "*Shall*" being the operative verb in the spec. For a long while, [GCC has been avant garde in its initialization support.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)

Comment: @bare_metal; See the updated answer. And please do not mix two entirely different data types for any behavior.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the grammar requires the expression to be an *assignment-expression*, which means that the top-level operator may not be a comma operator. (This is necessary to avoid ambiguity.)

Comment: @KeithThompson; Are you sure that expression is to be *assignment-expression*?

Comment: @haccks: Yes. [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.9p1: the syntax of an *initializer* is one of *assignment-expression*, `{` *initializer-list* `}`, or `{` *initializer-list* `,` `}`. (Note that an *assignment-expression* needn't have an assignment operator; any expression whose top-level operator is not a comma operator is an *assignment-expression*.)

Comment: @KeithThompson; Thanks for the valuable comment. Added that to the answer.

Comment: An *assignment-expression* may contain a comma operator, just not at the top level. `int q = { (1, 2) };` would be legal (but silly).

Comment: @KeithThompson; Example were given in the standard but I skipped that.

Comment: The linked bug report is about `gcc` segfaulting (the compiler, not the user executable) when faced with some ill-formed code, I don't think that bug is directly relevant to this question. Instead, gcc allows excess initializers on purpose (and ignores them) when in GNU mode.

Comment: @MattMcNabb; Not directly but it is related to this question.

Comment: @haccks I mean, the answer to "where did the excess initializers go?" isn't "a bug"; instead they are being ignored on purpose.

Comment: @MattMcNabb; For what purpose?

Comment: @haccks you'd have to ask the gcc developers that . Probably for backwards compatibility at this stage.

Comment: 6.7.9p11 is neither a syntax rule nor a constraint. Rather, 4p2 ("If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined.") applies. This arguably also violates 6.7.9p2 ("No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.") though, which is a constraint.