# How do you initialize an array of pointers to array in C?

Tags: c

compiler gives me the folowing error:

[Warning] assignment from incompatible pointer type

This was my try;

```
char (*array[10])[20],string[20] = "AEIOU"; array[2] = string;
```

[Array of pointers to an array of fixed size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348741/array-of-pointers-to-an-array-of-fixed-size) i already find this other question but wasn't useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array of pointers to an array of fixed size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348741/array-of-pointers-to-an-array-of-fixed-size) and several other answers found by searching SO

Comment: please post code one can compile...

Comment: The last statement should be `array[2] = &string;`. Strictly speaking, this is an assignment, not initialization.

Answer (score 2):

The most "natural" way to define an array of pointers to strings:

```
char *array[10];
```

This defines `array` as an array of 10 pointers to `char`.

Then

```
array[i] = string;
```

to make element `i` point to the first character of `string`.

From this assignment, `array[i]` is basically an alias for `string`.

---

Or if you really want a pointer to an array:

```
char (*array[10])[20];
array[i] = &string;
```

Note the use of the pointer-to operator `&` here, to get a pointer to the array itself. Also note that this is *very* different from the more "natural" way shown above. It all depends on what you actually want to accomplish, what your actual use-case and problem is.

---

And what happens with your currently shown code is that `string` *decay* to a pointer to its first element, so `string` is the same as `&string[0]`. Which has the type `char *`.

You currently define `array` as an array of pointers to arrays, so each element of `array` have the type `char (*)[20]`. That's the type you get with `&string`.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `char (*array[10])[20]`, it is declaring an array of 10 pointers, and each pointer points to an array of 20 characters (correct).

But in the following line:

```
array[2] = string;
```

it will show the warning "assignment from incompatible pointer type", bcz this is not allowed without proper typecast because the types are incompatible in C/C++. In your example, you are trying to **assign a array of character** `string` **to an element of an array of pointers to arrays of characters**. So it will cause warning.

You can change to use this to ignore the warning:

```
array[2] = &string;
```

array[2] will hold the address of of the `string` array, it is point to an array of characters. Therefore, this assignment is compatible.

Answer (score 1):

`C` compilers do not charge by line used.

Declare one thing per line.

- it is easier to read
- it is easier to locate a name or type a value
- it is easier to change
- in case of an error you just get the precise line number from the compiler

#### compare

```
char (*array[10])[20],string[20] = "AEIOU"; array[2] = string
```

#### with

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char string[20] = "AEIOU";
  char(*array[10])[20];

  array[2] = string;
}
```

#### line by line

```
    char string[20] = "AEIOU";
```

Is is ok but you should always use `const` as a reminder to yourself. If you do that an by mistake try to assign some value to `string` compiler will warn you, not someone at the phone when your code crashes.

```
    char array[2] = string;
```

Each `array` is a pointer to a `char[20]` so an `&` is missing. Write:

```
    char array[2] = &string;
```

#### not an initializer

```
    array[2] = &string;
```

This is an assignment. Not an initializer.

This is an initilizer:

```
    char(*array[10])[20]  = {
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    "A Test",
    string,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
};
```

This program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char string[20] = "AEIOU";
    char(*array[10])[20]  = {
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    "A Test",
    string,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
};

    array[2] = &string;
    printf("\
    #%d\t\"%s\"\n\
    #%d\t\"%s\"\n\
    #%d\t\"%s\"\n",
        2, array[2],
        3, array[3],
        4, array[4]);

    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
    #2  "AEIOU"
    #3  "A Test"
    #4  "AEIOU"
```

Note that `string` is `const char[20]`

Answer (score 0):

To the OP: you're over-thinking the array declaration, each array[N] is already an array pointer, e.g., array[2] is already an array pointer:

```
char string[20] = "AEIOU";

char array[10][20] = 
{
  "Test 0",  // array[0]
  "Test 1",  // array[1]
  "AEIOU"    // array[2]
  // ...
};

// Or, after declaration, e.g.:

strcpy(array[2], string);
```

or

```
char string[20] = "AEIOU";

char* array[10] =
{
    "Test 0",
    "Test 1",
    string
};

// Or
array[2] = string;
```

Comment: This is not an array of pointers.

Comment: @Coder No, it is not. `array[N]` is `char(*)[20]` as declared. It is a pointer to an array of precisely 20 `char`. And you code has no relation to the question. Mind the `*` in the original code.

Comment: @arfneto For `array[2]`, at the machine-level, a CPU register is loaded with the address of the char array, equal to `&array[2][0]`, and that address is used as a pointer to characters. Nit-picking about what "kind" of char pointer at the compiler-level, misses the much more important point that I am making here, and that is to either use a 2D array of characters or use a 1D array of pointers.

Comment: @Coder I see your point. But the compiler and the specification are always _nit-picking_

Comment: @arfneto compiler nit-picking, yes, try c++ :-) Although, I'd rather have the issues at compile-time rather than run-time :-)