# Why does j = --*p++ end up assigning 2 to j?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i[ ] = {3, 5};
   int *p = i;
   int j = --*p++;   

   printf("j = %d\n\n", j);

   return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why the answer is "`j = 2`"?

This code from the course notebook; they didn't explain it in the book.

Comment: What else would you expect it to be, and why?

Comment: One thing to learn here is never to do things like `--*p++`. There is absolutely no reason to write code like that, except *possibly* to confuse newbies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior can be described as **operator precedence** and it's something to do with how C compiler processed your code. In this case, the postfixed `++` operator takes precedence over `*` operator and incremented the pointer-to-array **after** you decremented the value of the dereferenced pointer with prefixed `--`, safe to say it's similarly written as such:

```
int main()
{
    int i[ ] = {3, 5};
    int *p = i;
    int j = --(*p++);   

    printf("j = %d\n\n", j);

    return 0;
}
```

References:

- [How to increment a pointer address and pointer's value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208021/how-to-increment-a-pointer-address-and-pointers-value)
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence