# Why does increment operator (++) not work when you reference using pointers in cpp/c

Tags: c++, c++14, increment

I was writing a code related to referencing in C/C++. I made a pointer and put it into a function that incremented it. In the function, I wrote `*ptr++` and tried to increment the value of the integer the pointer was pointing at.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void increment(int *ptr)
{
    int &ref = *ptr;
    *ptr++; // gets ignored?
    ref++;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    increment(&a);
    cout << a;

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why I can't increment the variable? I have tried incrementing it using `+=1`, and it works but not by using `++` operator?

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Can you please tell me what's in that picture? Unfortunately I am blind, and my screen reader only spells out gibberish when it comes to that line.

Comment: Perfect dupe: [How to increment a pointer address and pointer's value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208021/how-to-increment-a-pointer-address-and-pointers-value)

Comment: [C++ operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increment a pointer address and pointer's value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208021/how-to-increment-a-pointer-address-and-pointers-value)

Answer (score 6):

`++` has higher precedence than `*`, so `*ptr++` is treated as `*(ptr++)`. This increments the pointer, not the number that it points to.

To increment the number, use `(*ptr)++`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is:

```cpp
*ptr++;
```

Which is equivalent to:

```cpp
*(ptr++);
```

Which means pointer is incremented first and then dereferenced. this happens because increment operator `++` has higher precedence than dereferance operator `*` . So you should use:

```cpp
(*ptr)++;
```

Here first pointer is dereferenced then incremented.